# Unable to open ANACONDA or SPYDER: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, pyqt5, conda

I have seen all previous posts related to it but none of them worked for me

What I did is:

- Installed MS Visual Studio 2017 comm, 2019 comm , Visual c++ 2008 to 2019
- Installed anaconda(x64) python3.8 windows 10 64bit
- cmd typed "anaconda-navigator"

GOT THIS ERR

```
(base) C:\Users\SHUBHAM>anaconda-navigator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SHUBHAM\anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\SHUBHAM\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 103, in main
    from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app
  File "C:\Users\SHUBHAM\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 32, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.widgets.dialogs import MessageBoxInformation
  File "C:\Users\SHUBHAM\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from qtpy import QtSvg
  File "C:\Users\SHUBHAM\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\QtSvg.py", line 14, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtSvg import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtSvg: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

My attempts NOTHING WOKRED!:

- pip install pyqt5 qt spyder anaconda
- conda update conda
- conda update anaconda
- conda update anaconda-navigator
- pip install pyside2
- pip install pyqt5-tools
- conda info working,
- pip show pyqt5 and import `pyqt5.__file__` are showing same location
- python3.dll present
- pip install bootstrap.py
- Tried with both admin and without admin
- PyQt5 version 5.12.3
- spyder version 4.2.0

  `conda info`

```
    C:\Users\SHUBHAM>conda info    
         active environment : None
                shell level : 0
           user config file : C:\Users\SHUBHAM\.condarc
     populated config files : C:\Users\SHUBHAM\.condarc
              conda version : 4.9.2
        conda-build version : 3.20.5
             python version : 3.8.5.final.0
           virtual packages : __cuda=11.1=0
                              __win=0=0
                              __archspec=1=x86_64
           base environment : C:\Users\SHUBHAM\anaconda3  (writable)
               channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                              https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                              https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                              https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                              https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                              https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
              package cache : C:\Users\SHUBHAM\anaconda3\pkgs
                              C:\Users\SHUBHAM\.conda\pkgs
                              C:\Users\SHUBHAM\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
           envs directories : C:\Users\SHUBHAM\anaconda3\envs
                              C:\Users\SHUBHAM\.conda\envs
                              C:\Users\SHUBHAM\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                   platform : win-64
                 user-agent : conda/4.9.2 requests/2.25.0 CPython/3.8.5 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19041
              administrator : False
                 netrc file : None
               offline mode : False
```

This is working

[image]

I am able to run Jupyer Notebook but not anaconda or spyder

paths:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uninstalling anaconda3 and visual studio and fresh installing anaconda3 worked.